# Escape backslash from the json created through requests.get()

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-escape-characters

I am gathering data through requests.get() from a rest-api url and modifying that data and pushing the modified data back again to the link through requests.put(). Problem is that the modified html code that I am sending through request.put() has the backslash character which is causing a Internal Server error of status code 500. I will show you part of the html code that I gather by using requests.put() command and it has the backslash.

```
<p><br /></p><table><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th><p>JIRA</p></th><th><p>Type</p></th><th><p>PR</p></th><th><p>Commit</p></th><th><p>Author</p></th><th><p>Date</p></th></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5742\">IAPETUSZ-5742</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/9739\">9739</a></p></td><td><p>caf1229bb6a</p></td><td><p>ang</p></td><td><p>Thu, 4 Feb 2021 18:02:33 -0800</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5991\">IAPETUSZ-5991</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/9971\">9971</a></p></td><td><p>db996d499cb</p></td><td><p>Mo</p></td><td><p>Fri, 19 Feb 2021 14:18:27 -0800</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5971\">IAPETUSZ-5971</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/10067\">10067</a></p></td><td><p>216905485f1</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p>Fri, 26 Feb 2021 00:12:01 -0800</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-6200\">IAPETUSZ-6200</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/10126\">10126</a></p></td><td><p>ca28f68a0a5</p></td><td><p>Chowdhury</p></td><td><p>Tue, 9 Mar 2021 16:37:18 -0800</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5608\">IAPETUSZ-5608</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/9510\">9510</a></p></td><td><p>b316a1c21be</p></td><td><p>Chowdhury</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.sandisk.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5075\">IAPETUSZ-5075</a></p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/8971\">8971</a></p></td><td><p>69fc6076c4f</p></td><td><p>ti</p></td><td><p>Fri, 11 Dec 2020 12:03:21 -0800</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAPETUSZ-5757\">IAPETUSZ-5757</a></p></td><td><p>Bug</p></td><td><p><a href=\"https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/FPGCSS/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/9666\">9666</a></p></td><td><p>dfe303b4260</p></td><td><p>rg</p></td><td><p>Fri, 29 Jan 2021 09:54:31 -0800</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><p><br /></p>
```

As you can see from above the html code has <a href="https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects/CSSai/repos/cssh2p2/pull-requests/9739" which has backslash and is causing the problem. The backslash does not get printed here so you couldn't see it but its there is the code-block above.
Below is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594?expand=body.storage',
                        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@wdc')).json()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response['body']['storage']['value'], 'html.parser')

html = soup.contents

for idx in range(0, len(html)):
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="https://bitbucket.ai.com/projects//pull-requests/")
    if idx == 2:
        print("Contents of TABLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
        print(html[idx])
        print('\n')
        # [br.extract() for br in html[idx].find_all('br')]
        for br in html[idx].find_all('br'):
            br.extract()
            html.insert(idx, new_tag)
            html[idx].string = "MY_Link"

pass_string = str(soup)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Feature Automation - POST data","space":{"key":"CSSai"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":2}}'

response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@wdc'))

print(response.json())
```

I think the JSON data does not like the " and so reuquests.put() is showing the status code 500.

Comment: Where in all of that code are you encountering and passing through that URL?

Comment: Also remember not to let yourself confuse the difference between the CONTENT of a string and the REPRESENTATION of a string.  If you have a string containing `abc"def"ghi`, it's going to print as `"abc\"def\"ghi"`.  The backslashes are not part of the string.  They are just in the printed representation.  This can be very confusing at first.

Comment: @TimRoberts I figured the manipulation part is not important so I did not include it before, but I did now. It does not really cause any difference. I also copied the JSON content i.e response['body']['storage']['value'] directly from the url to my request.put() command and still get same error but if I get rid of the backslash it works. How should I escape that backslash for requests.put()

Comment: @TimRoberts I have updated the html code as well

Comment: @GarrGodfrey No I am not. How do I encode the JSON? I figured once I gather data from requests.get() its already gets encoded

Comment: `soup` is a python object, so using str will format as a python object. You'd need to import json and use json.dumps.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I tried that by doing pass_string = json.dumps(soup) and then passing it like I showed above in the question. But I get an error saying that the HTML code I shown above in question is not JSON serializable.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey If I make the one backslash double backslash the whole request.put() function works. But since the backslash will be inside the soup variable object I do not know how to turn it into double backslash.

Comment: idk what `str(soup)` gives you. I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup. If that gives you the HTML string, then you would need to json encode that html string. `json.dumps(str(soup))`.  It should already include "" in that case

Comment: but, ideally, make your entire "data" an object. Don't do any json formatting yourself. Make that a python object and do json.dumps on `data`